# Copy columns from one sheet to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with multiple sheets in. I have a sheet called "MergedData", I need to copy columns `B` & `L` into a workbook called "Bookings.xls"

Column B is a Word Order number and L is a £value, I need it to copy over values that are over £0.01 and exclude everything with a nil value.

The data will need to be placed into Rows of columns `A` & `B` in the Bookings workbook, starting at row 9.

The data will need to erase every month when the code is run.

I will be applying this code to multiple workbook for different Contractors. So the code cannot Hard-Lock to the original file. Needs to be the Active Workbook, the `Bookings.xls` file is a static workbook in all contractor folders.

Thanks for all the support.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim LastDRow As Integer, _
        InitWorkSheet As Worksheet, _
        DestWorkSheet As Worksheet, _
        myData As Workbook, _
        LastWRow As Integer

Set InitWorkSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MergedData") 'Or ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set myData = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Bookings.xls")
DoEvents
Set DestWorkSheet = myData.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Or myData.Sheets("Sheet1")

With InitWorkSheet
    LastDRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox LastDRow
    For i = LastDRow To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, "L") < 0 Then
        Else
            LastWRow = DestWorkSheet.Cells(DestWorkSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If LastWRow < 9 Then LastWRow = 9
            DestWorkSheet.Cells(LastWRow, 1) = .Cells(i, "B")
            DestWorkSheet.Cells(LastWRow, 2) = .Cells(i, "L")
        End If
    Next i
End With

myData.Save

End Sub`
```

Comment: What have you written on this problem so far?

Comment: @USFBS Hi, i have update OP to include what i have now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this and let me know :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim LastDRow As Integer, _
        InitWorkSheet As Worksheet, _
        DestWorkSheet As Worksheet, _
        myData As Workbook, _
        LastWRow As Integer

Set InitWorkSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MergedData")
Set myData = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Bookings.xls")
Set DestWorkSheet = myData.Sheets("Sheet1")

DestWorkSheet.Cells.ClearContents

With InitWorkSheet
    LastDRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LastDRow 'To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, "L") < 0.01 Then
        Else
            LastWRow = DestWorkSheet.Cells(DestWorkSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If LastWRow < 9 Then LastWRow = 9
            DestWorkSheet.Cells(LastWRow, 1) = .Cells(i, "B")
            DestWorkSheet.Cells(LastWRow, 2) = .Cells(i, "L")
        End If
    Next i
End With

myData.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: i get a Run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error on     'For i = .Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1' thanks

Comment: I don't know id my original code is correct, i have a feeling that it is not.

Comment: Hi mate, still gives me the same error on LastWRow = myData.ActiveSheet.Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Ok so what is the name of the Sheet you want to copy data to?

Comment: hi it needs to go into sheet 1, starting at row 9 in columns A & B

Comment: Try the new version and if it is not working, change to the 2nd possibility in `Set DestWorkSheet = ...`

Comment: Hi mate, i have tried the change but and still getting Run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error on LastWRow = myData.ActiveSheet.Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row. sorry for being a pain! If you know of a different code that would work, don't have to use the code i have. If its easier.THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP!!!!

Comment: I changed code since... Anyway, if you put the correct names of the workbook and sheet between brackets `"` like here : `Workbooks("Test1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")` this should work smoothly, it is just the references of these that are missing in there errors.

Comment: Hi Mate, i have changed the sheet names, but still get the same error, i have uploaded some text files for referencing. if you can have a look for me. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1Z1ZIW5rn8JflFvUWlhSzRfdkx0QW4yT2lVRDh6UkxnTXJ6djlwTzdORmx1MnNvUDFOazA&authuser=0

Comment: I can't access to your file but the code is working except for the file's name and the sheet's name, so take time to be sure of these and try the last version with your updates ;) I'll be offline for a moment but I'll see later if you managed it ;)

Comment: ok i have got it to work, but it is only coping the first row, rather than coping them all???

Comment: OK, what does the msgbox says on this one? It should be the number of your last row in the sheet to scan, if it is not that is were the problem is coming for

Comment: Hi, it's not giving me an error, it copy's data but only the first line of the source data

Comment: I meant try the edit, I put a variable and a message box to be sure of what you'll see

Comment: appoligies i completely missed that!! i have tried the code and the message box says 44, but still only has the one line copied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79392/discussion-between-atame-and-r3uk).